# What is appropriate size of icon for 3D Touch shortcut item on home screen?

Tags: ios, ios9, 3dtouch

I couldn't find it on [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1).

But I mean, what is the size of following icons?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below mentioned article, there is a note:

[image]

Once you download this, you will see that there is a recommended size:

- **104x104** for **3x**
- **70x70** for **2x**

[image]

Comment: Here's direct link for downloading zip with icon examples https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/Quick-Action-Guides.zip Usually Apple gives exact sizes of icons in documentation. But not for shortcut item. It isn't easy to find these sizes.

Comment: that's just weird - if 2x is 70px, shouldn't 3x be 105?

Comment: @Bastek That is what I thought

Comment: It's crazy that Apple doesn't specify the icon pixel size on their website..... pathetic really. Can you put a link up to the article? Thanks.

Comment: check this link for quick action icon size https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple will automatically size and re-colour the icons, it's better to use a PDF, which has the added benefit of looking sharper and a reduced risk of causing clipped edges if margins aren't used.

Here's a comparison of PDF vs PNG (exact same icon, originally and SVG exported from Sketch):

[image]

The size is also the same.
[image]